# DataContext binding to a rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a class Student with 3 attributes (first name, last name, age).

In .xaml ( basically two rectangles - each containing 3 text blocks bind to those 3 attributes).

```
<Border  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Name="rectangle1" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=FirstName}"  Padding="2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=LastName}" Padding="2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Age}" Padding="2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16"  Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AvailabilityToBrushConverter1}, Path=IsAvailable}" Name="rectangle2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=FirstName}"  Padding="2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=LastName}" Padding="2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Age}" Padding="2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

In .xaml.cs

```
Student student1 = new Student { FirstName = "James", LastName = "Peter", Age= 12 ,IsAvailable=true  };
Student student2 = new Student { FirstName = "Mark", LastName = "Smith", Age = 20 };
```

after InitializeComponent

```
InitializeComponent();     
DataContext = student1;
```

When i run i get

> James Peter 12
>  James Peter 12

I want on form load

> James Peter 12
>  Mark  Smith 20

I tried to use this, but didn't work:

```
rectangle1.DataContext=student1;
rectangle2.DataContext=student2;
```

How do i set two different values for these 2 rectangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Rectangles` do *not* contain the `TextBlocks`, in both cases a `StackPanel` does, you should set the `DataContext` on them instead.